# linespacing local font environment

Tags: environments, line-spacing, baseline

I have a multi-paragraph section of `tiny`-font within a larger document of `normal`-size text.

The last paragraph within this section seems to get double spacing: 
[image: Imgur]

I can fix the problem by putting a blank line before the final `\end{tiny}` but I don't know why this works.

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{report}

\begin{document}
This is normal size.

\begin{tiny}
This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. This is tiny size. 

Why is this paragraph double spaced?  Why is this paragraph double spaced?  Why is this paragraph double spaced?  Why is this paragraph double spaced?  Why is this paragraph double spaced?  Why is this paragraph double spaced?  Why is this paragraph double spaced?
\end{tiny}

\end{document}
```

Comment: is it not double spacing, but actually returning to the linespacing of 'normal size', without actually changing the font yet to normal size?

Comment: The large and complicated discussion in the older question you link only incidentally mentions the the crucial information I sought.  My question is a needle, sufficiently different from the haystack! I would keep the question, and not delete it.

Comment: @egreg I probably won't vote to re-open but the question isn't a duplicate of that question (or even that related) even though the answers are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave a blank line before

```
\end{tiny}
```

Whenever you have a font size change that could involve line breaking you need to include the end of paragraph in the scope, otherwise the paragraph ends outside the scope when baseline spacing has reverted to the previous value

Comment: similar things have been asked before: [Uneven line height in XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127684/579), [vertical spacing of entire section changes when using sciptsize environment for table]( http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153999/579); [Why \\ increases interline spacing before the command in center environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123872/579}.  (not saying any one is an exact duplicate, but they all show how paragraph scoping affects baselines.)

Comment: It was the logic which escaped me, but now I can see the reasons. tx.